# Passing arbitrary arguments to handlebars helpers?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, internationalization, handlebars.js

sorry if this has been asked a million times before but I can't seem to find a satisfactory answer anywhere.

I'm trying to build a handlebars helper to tie into my i18n library and I need it to accept any number of named arguments as follows:

```
{{i18n yml.text.definition count=2 name="Alex" ... param="hello}}
```

which will translate to a call like this:

```
i18n.t("yml.text.definition", { count: 2, name: "Alex", ... param: "hello"})
```

Is this possible, or am I totally out of my tree?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Give the following helper:

```
{{myHelper "foo" this ... key=value ...}}
```

You can get the data with the following declaration:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('name', function(param1, param2, options) {
  param1 // The string "foo"
  param2 // some object in that context
  options.hash // { key: value }
});
```

Each parameter of the function is the parameter passed in {{myHelper param1 param2}}. But the remaining will be an object with some special/private information. With that object you retrieve the key=value information using the hash object.

If the paramter supplied to the helper is quoted, like "param1", the string is returned, otherwise it's resolved to some object in that context.

In your case you will need:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('i18n', function(property, options) {        
    var hash = options.hash;    
    return 'i18n.t(' + property + ', { count: ' + hash.count + ', name: ' + hash.name + ', param: ' + hash.param + '})';
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle with this working http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/64Uvs/

I hope it helps

Comment: Oh wow, this totally works. Whenever I did it, options.hash was always empty.. very strange. Does it make a difference if you use RegisterHelper or RegisterBoundHelper? I will give it a go first thing tomorrow and report back!

Comment: You don't use either `registerHelper` or `registerBoundHelper` anymore.  Now you just do `Ember.Handlebars.helper` as shown above.  After the function, you can pass the name of properties of the main object that are dependencies of your helper.  http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/#toc_dependencies

Comment: I guess this is for Ember 1.0 and higher? I'm still using the latest RC (planning to upgrade soon).. does this handle something like keyBinding="path.to.parameter"?

Comment: The last changes in helpers that I remember is: Inclusion of `Ember.Handlebars.helper`, this is an old change. And parameters using quotes be considered strings instead of binding. So in old versions `{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="firstName"}}` work. But in recent versions you will need to remove the quotes like `valueBinding=firstName`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('i18n', function(context, block) {
  return i18n.t(context, { count: block.hash.count, name: block.hash.name, ... param: block.hash.param}); 
});
```

Comment: This answer is on the right track but I think it needs to be 'block.hash' However at least in the RC versions of Ember the registerBoundHelper doesn't pass through arguments that I can see.

Comment: Handlebars.registerHelper('I18n', function(context, block) {
        var count = (block.hash.count) ? parseInt(block.hash.count) : 0;
        return I18n.t(context, { count: count, name: block.hash.name});  // Specify any extra parameter here!
    });